# swerve steering controller: unable to load the controller

Tags: ros-control, controller-manager

The error thrown is this: `Could not load class 'swerve_steering_controller/SwerveSteeringController': Could not find library corresponding to plugin swerve_steering_controller/SwerveSteeringController. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.`
I have saved the controller just as a package within catkin_ws.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.